# Can't find module node-pty after changing name of directory

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules, node-pty

I'm working on a Typescript React & Electron app that has `node-pty` as a dependency. I have it installed in `release/app` because it's a native dependency and won't work if it's in the regular `node-modules` folder at the top level.

Basically, I changed the name of the parent directory where all of my app files are, and now when I run `npm start` I get the error

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'node-pty'
Require stack:
- D:\projects\<new_folder_name>\src\main\main.ts
- D:\projects\<new_folder_name>\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js
```

even though everything is still installed correctly and the only thing I changed is the name of the directory. I've done a shallow search through all my project files and I couldn't find any reference to old name of the directory.

For reference, here is a rough snapshot of my folder structure:

```
<new_folder_name>
 |- ...
 |- src
    |- ...
    |- main
       |- ...
       |- main.ts
    |- renderer
 |- node_modules
 |- release
    |- app
       |- node_modules
          |- nan
          |- node-pty
          |- .package-lock.json
       |- package-lock.json
       |- package.json
 |- package-lock.json
 |- package.json
```

`package.json` in the top directory does not contain any reference to `node-pty`, while the inner `package.json` in `release/app` does. I'm not sure what other information would be relevant, as all I did was change the name of the folder.

I've tried deleting both `node_modules` and reinstalling all dependencies, even creating a new project and copy-pasting my code. If anyone could give any ideas as to what is causing node to be unable to locate this package now (maybe it's related to an abspath being stored somewhere?) that would be great. Thanks!